# Firebase User not deleting from ListView of Android

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

As per Title i want to clear some flow of my app. First Employee gets Login to application and will view list of customers in ListView of Android. I want that when employee wish to delete any customer they can by selecting any customer for any reason.

I did code on delete button as shown below:

Found from StackOverflow itself

```
 FirebaseUser  user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
             user.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                   // FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Customer Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
                else
                {
                    Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Customer Not Deleted", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Now the issue is when this code runs.... it delete the employee which is logged in and not that user/customer to whom he wish to delete.

Please guide me what changes i should make to fulfill my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

Get's the current user and that's what it deletes,what you should do instead is:

```
String uid=...//of which user you want to
Firebase users = myFirebaseRef.child("users");
users.equalTo(uid);
```

Then call the delete method

Comment: Thankyou for your gudiance Sir....I wrote this code in my app and it shows getUserAsync() cannot be resolved. What can be the solution for that?

Comment: This will delete the User stored in database. I want to delete User from Authentication but i have uid as a push id in user/customer table in firebase. Is there something to delete account from authentication based on matching of Uid with my push id(which is uid itself) ?

Comment: I tried this updated code. Now it shows Firebase cannot resolve symbol. Do i need to import something other as i already imported everthing i.e import com.google.firebase.*;

Comment: what do you mean match uid with push id?give an example,also what symbol can't be resolved?

Comment: Error Solved. Thankyou Very much